# Does Azure SQL support Kerberos?

Tags: azure, kerberos

We are migrating an ASP.NET application onto Azure. Target state selected as Cloud Service Web role to host application component and Database onto Azure SQL/SQL Database. Currently the application is configured onto Kerberos in the source environment. Please let me know if Kerberos can be configured onto Target Environment without any issues.

Are they any specific steps to be done for Kerberos to work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to use Azure Active Directory. This method of authentication is in preview atm and only available for Azure SQL v12. There's possibly a lot of steps involved for your scenario from populating your Azure AD to setup your application. Check these references:

[Integrating your on-premises identities with Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/)

[Azure SQL Database security guidelines and limitations](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-security-guidelines/)

[Connecting to SQL Database By Using Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/)

Comment: OP asked about Kerberos, not seeing any reference in these articles about Kerberos authentication.